# InvalidPathException for chinese filename

Tags: java, locale, chinese-locale

I am trying to copy a file on an ubuntu machine using the java statement

`Files.copy(new File("/tmp/source/测试.xlsx").toPath(), new File("/tmp/dest/测试.xlsx").toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

But i get the following error

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains
>   unmappable characters:
>   /tmp/source/测试.xlsx   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_91]  at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.(UnixPath.java:71) ~[na:1.8.0_91]   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_91]    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234) ~[na:1.8.0_91]

This runs perfectly fine when i run it on my eclipse. 
Also, the code works fine with all english characters.

Comment: "_This runs perfectly fine when i run it on my eclipse_". Are you saying that it does not work when you run this program in command line ?

Comment: Does your Eclipse run on a different operating system than Ubuntu?

Comment: @MadPiranha On my eclipse, i run it as a standalone java application and pass the parameters using main method. The project i am running on ubuntu is a maven project deployed on tomcat which is triggered using an API REST call

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt My eclipse is running on mac OS.

Answer (score 8):

This could be a [JDK Bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8003228)

Set the following system properties `sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8` and `file.encoding=UTF-8`.

- Check [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/add-system-properties.html) to add system properties in tomcat maven plugin.
- Use the `-D` option if you are running a `java` program in command line. (`-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`)

Comment: This works on Java but when running Java via the groovy binary mine seems to ignore the command line properties. Any idea why? `groovy -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 myfile.groovy`

Comment: In answer to my own question, as a workaround you can use `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's related to the locale setting on the machine where you want to run the application.

Take folloing snippet

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path source = Paths.get("/tmp/source/测试.xlsx");
        Path destination = Paths.get("/tmp/dest/测试.xlsx");
        Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

compile

```
javac -encoding UTF8 Main.java
```

run with locale UTF8

```
LANG=en_US.utf8 java sub.optimal.playground.Main
```

The destination file will be created (assuming the directory exist and you have the right permissions).

run with locale C

```
LANG=C java sub.optimal.playground.Main
```

output

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains
    unmappable characters: /tmp/source/??.xlsx
```

Check if the session in which you want to run the application uses a locale which supports UTF8 (simple run `locale`).